# QTableWidget or QTableView for toggling cell images

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview, qtablewidget

I am looking for a guidance over here. I want to have a a table with rows of data. One of the column is empty dedicated to user input. if user likes the data in the row clicking on the empty cell will display an image i.e. heart. if user changes her/his mind later clicking on the image will erase it.
I am not sure of QTableView will support it functionality.
If I am wrong with my assumption that it can be done with QTableView or QTableWidget, i appreciate any guidance in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setGeometry(600, 200, 330, 180)

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Product', 'Description', 'Likes/UnLikes'])
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tableWidget)

        for x in range(3):
            self.button = QPushButton('Likes/UnLikes', self) 
            self.button.setFlat(True)
            self.tableWidget.setItem(x, 0, QTableWidgetItem('Product{}'.format(x)))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(x, 1, QTableWidgetItem('Description'))
            self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(x, 2, self.button)

            self.button.clicked.connect(
                lambda state, w=self.tableWidget.cellWidget(x,2), r=x, c=2: self.button_pushed(w, r, c)
            )

    def button_pushed(self, w, r, c): 
        if w.text() != "Likes/UnLikes":
            w.setIcon(QIcon(""))
            w.setText("Likes/UnLikes")
        else:
            w.setIcon(QIcon("E:/_Qt/img/heart.png"))
            w.setText(" Likes")

        w.setIconSize(QSize(20, 20))
        self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(r, c, w)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w   = MainWindow()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That will work. I didn't think to use buttons.